# Getting trailing arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a script which takes two argument groups - the option `-e` and the directories/files `/path/to/file` and `/path/to/folder`.

```
./myscript -e /path/to/file /path/to/folder
```

*I know about `$@` to get all the arguments and `$#` to get the number of arguments.*

An example of this would be `rm`. With `rm` one can pass arguments `-rf` along with directories `/path/to/file /path/to/another/file /path/to/some/folder` and so on.

In my script, the option is handled as `$1`, but how should I handle the trailing arguments rm-style?

Comment: I tend to use the 'shift' operator to manage multiple argument parsing.  http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams

Comment: In addition to `shift`, trailing arguments can be handled with `${@:n}` where in your case  `${@:2}` would return all arguments following `-e`.

Comment: `shift` once, handle `-e` then keep shifting, or just use `${@:2}`.

Comment: I see, thanks. So allow me to summarise: `${@:2}` to handle args `$2` and after OR use `while (( $# ))`.

Comment: Yep, you got it. The `${@:n}` syntax can be used to handle all trailing args where `n` can be any number `1 - $#`. (just depends on how many of the trailing args you want). In your example, if you wanted to `rm` all files after `-e` it would be `rm ${@:2}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, in addition to the `shift` operator, you can also use `${@:n}` syntax to return all trailing *positional parameters* beginning with `n`. Continuing with your example using the first parameter as `'-e'` and sending the remaining arguments to `rm -rf`, you could use:

```
rm -rf "${@:2}"
```

A short practical example will give you a better feel for it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    echo "\${@:$i} : ${@:$i} ($(($#-i+1)) args)"
done
```

**Example**

```
$ bash atargs.sh -e dir/a.txt dir/b.txt dir/c.txt
${@:1} : -e dir/a.txt dir/b.txt dir/c.txt (4 args)
${@:2} : dir/a.txt dir/b.txt dir/c.txt (3 args)
${@:3} : dir/b.txt dir/c.txt (2 args)
${@:4} : dir/c.txt (1 args)
```

**note:** you do not get a free pass with filenames with spaces, etc. While the number of arguments is properly preserved, and if you had passed the last arguments as `"dir/c with a space.txt"`, the argument numbers would remain the same, and the last line of output above would properly be:

```
${@:4} : dir/c with a space.txt (1 args)
```

you could not simply pass `"${@:2}"` to `rm -rf`. In the case of spaces in *quoted arguments* you would still be required to use a `for i in "${@:2}"; do rm -rm "$i"; done` or `shift` type iteration through the arguments for a proper removal.